# Visual Studio Code - set argoments while debugging in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging, gcc, command-line-arguments

This is my simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 
    printf("%d\n", argc); 
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) printf("%s\n", argv[i]); 
    return 0; 
}
```

If I compile with terminal and run

```
gcc -o test test.c
./test foo bar
```

I get

```
3
foo
bar
```

so works perfectly. Now I would like debug this program passing arguments <"foo"> <"bar"> but i don't understand how.

I tried with CTRL + SHIFT + P -> "C/C++: edit Configurations (JSON)" and adding the line

```
"compilerArgs": ["bar", "foo"]
```

but still doesn't work. Debugger says "argc: 1" when it should be 3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL3FG.png)

This is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name":"gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type":"cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Assignment1/",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "externalConsole": false
        }
    ]
}
```

task.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: These are not "compilerArgs", these are "args" in your launch configuration.

Answer (score 0):

put them right

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name":"gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type":"cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Assignment1/",
            "args": ["bar", "foo"], // <<<<<===== here
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "externalConsole": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work https://imgur.com/a/Ar0EJZ1

Answer (score 0):

I solved, I missed to add "/test" in lauch.json:

```
...
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/Assignment1/test"
"args": ["bar", "foo"],
```

now everything works